# Infinite loop in Tkinter python code

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to run a simple Tkinter program that opens a program when you click a button.  The code is listed below.  I use a command to call a program that then calls a fortran program.  However, when I click on the button, it opens the program but the menu of the program i'm calling goes into an infinite loop......the offending code seems to be in the button1Click module.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
from Tkinter import * 
import os, sys 
from win32com.client import Dispatch 
xlApp=Dispatch('Excel.Application') 
_PSSBINPATH=r"C:\Program Files\PTI\PSSE32\PSSBIN" 
os.environ['PATH']=_PSSBINPATH+';'+os.environ['PATH'] 
sys.path.insert(0,_PSSBINPATH) 
import redirect; redirect.psse2py() 
import psspy 

class MyApp: 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        self.myParent = parent  ### (7) remember my parent, the root 
        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent) 
        self.myContainer1.pack() 

        self.button1 = Button(self.myContainer1) 
        self.button1.configure(text="OK", background= "green") 
        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT) 
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.button1Click) ### (1) 

        self.button2 = Button(self.myContainer1) 
        self.button2.configure(text="Cancel", background="red") 
        self.button2.pack(side=RIGHT) 
        self.button2.bind("<Button-1>", self.button2Click) ### (2) 

    def button1Click(self,event):    ### (3) 
        psspy.runiplanfile(r"C:\MNTACT\Contingency Program\work\contingency-31-4.irf") 
        if self.button1["background"] == "green": ### (4) 
            self.button1["background"] = "yellow" 
        else: 
            self.button1["background"] = "green" 

    def button2Click(self, event):  ### (5) 
        self.myParent.destroy()     ### (6) 


root = Tk() 
myapp = MyApp(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think there's an infinite loop happening? I see no loop in button1Click, unless the loop is in `runiplanfile`. Are you using "infinite loop" to mean simply that the GUI has stopped responding?

Tkinter is single threaded and cannot process events except via the event loop. If one event takes a long time to process, the GUI will hang until the processing of that event is completed. If you're exec'ing an external process and waiting for it to complete, your GUI will appear to be frozen until that process finishes.